# How to show variables of class (IN MVC Model) in a view in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model class with the name of contract_detail their is a field called season in this class i create an other class a define the season field in this new class now i want to show the all variables if new class in a view in drop down list.

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Season, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Season, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Season)), new { @class = "form-control" })

                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Season, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Season, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
//My season class which define field season
public class Season
    {
        public Season(string value) { Value = value; }

        public string Value { get; set; }

        public static Season S1 { get { return new Season("2018-2019"); } }
        public static Season S2 { get { return new Season("Debug"); } }
        public static Season S3 { get { return new Season("Info"); } }
        public static Season S4 { get { return new Season("Warning"); } }
        public static Season S5 { get { return new Season("Error"); } }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Focusing just on the drop down list your current code doesn't work for a couple of reasons. Mainly, the Season class you have defined is a class and not an Enumeration so `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Season))` won't exactly work.

I would think about restructuring your view model.  You may need to update your other form inputs to fit this view model, but it should work for the drop down list your looking to achieve.

```
@model ViewModel
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Season, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSeason, Model.SeasonList, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Season, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Season, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

public class ViewModel
{
    public string SelectedSeason { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Season> Seasons { get; set; }
    public SelectList SeasonList { get; set; }

    public ViewModel() 
    {
        Seasons = new List<Season>() 
        {
            { new Season("2018-2019") },
            { new Season("Debug") },
            { new Season("Info") },
            { new Season("Warning") },
            { new Season("Error") },
        };

        SeasonList = new SelectList(Seasons, "Value", "Value");
    }
}
```